# Tokenizing document while retaining formatting

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js

I need to tokenize the open document into words and for each word I need to check whether it is **Bold**, *Italic* or Underlined. I need to do this for all parts of the document.

Up to now, my application was ignoring formatting and using `range.text.split(/\s+/);` to tokenize. Is there a similar method I can use to split the documents into words and retain the formatting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards with the Body.search method. You could define a wildcard expression that matches every range that ends with a blank space. For an example of search being used with wildcards, see the queueFetchOfInlineRanges function in this file: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-MarkdownConversion/blob/master/Word-Add-in-JavaScript-MDConversionWeb/Home.js

Comment: I thought that but the last word in a paragraph would not have a blank space at the end... What wildcard expression would you suggest using to pick up everything?

Comment: Maybe you could use a wildcard expression that matches every run of text that ends in EITHER a space OR punctuation mark OR line break. There are lots of free libraries of regular expressions (which is another name for wildcard expression) online. Try to find a regular expression that matches the connotation of "word" that meets your needs. Then rewrite it in the syntax of Word JavaScript wildcard expressions. (E.g., escaping a special character is different in programmatic Word wildcard expressions than in most regular expression syntax.)